# Background image goes to solid colour after dynamic content is added on Android

Tags: android, css

My goal is to have a full background image behind the content of my website. I am using the following CSS to achieve this:

```
body {
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

My issue is that while this works perfectly on the desktop:
[image: Background image on the web]
and initially works on mobile:

[image: Working on mobile]

As soon as JS puts in new content:

```
posts.innerHTML = newHTML + posts.innerHTML;
```

Whatever image is displaying (I've tried multiple images) will go to what appears to be a fixed colour based on the image:

[image: Solid colour instead]

When you scroll when this happens a white border appears at the bottom (which fills with the colour as soon as you stop scrolling)

[image: White border]

How do I fix these issues? If you want to see all of the code it's on GitHub: https://github.com/NickGeek/Campfyre

Comment: This looks strange .. but the problem surely is with the `cover` or `fixed` background properties .. its scaling the background to the size of window .. can you try adding `width: 100%; height: 100%;` to the `body` css ?

Comment: @SyedQarib I tried adding width: 100%; and height: 100%; didn't change anything. If I remove fixed the background stops working on desktop

Comment: body, html {height: 100%}

Comment: Just wondering, what is the height of the body element if you remove height 100%? Is it shorter than the content?

Comment: Nope, nothing is added to the DOM before <body>

Comment: is it correct to apply this style to html selector? `html {background:....`

Comment: Applying the background to the HTML selector would still break, my working solution is below if you are interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by using the following css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color:#000000;
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

This allowed me to have a full sized image without using the fixed property, which was breaking on android, or the cover property which was also breaking (no matter what element I put it on). I also had to put background-color: transparent; on the body.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the body is set to the height of the viewport. Cant grow further, and does not inherit the real height of the whole page. So the solution is to add an helper div that contains the dom:

so change:

```
<body>
 ...code
</body>
```

to

```
<body><div class="scrollme-not-body">
 ...code
</div></body>
```

Try with

```
html {

    background: url(http://campfyre.org/img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

    background-size: cover

}
```

Comment: It seems cover and fixed are issues, even on html or another div it will break.