# Scaling down background for mobile phones

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a background image with resolution 1900x1200,and the background is showing just fine on most resolutions but when i get down to mobile resolutions i have got a problem.The background is streched out and it is very ugly.In my mobile version of website there is a lot of height(on android s4 i have almost 3000px in height),now my question is how can i make my background look better on mobile phones?

Here is my current css code for background.I know i have to add some new code in media query just for the specific phone resolution,but i dont know what...any help or explanation?

```
body {
background: url(mypicture.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I suggest using a different image entirely for mobile devices, a 1900x1200 image is likely to be very large (a few hundred KiB?) which won't work well for users on slow data connections.

Comment: You can always change the body background using media queries.

Comment: Your code looks right. You don't need to add media queries when you use "cover" —unless you want o use different images for each query, which I strongly recommend you.

Comment: Some brainstorming ideas you can try... Try changing the background to another element besides the body. If the background is on the body, some iOS mobile devices will display the background related to the size of the body/length of the page, instead of the viewport. Fixed can be a problem in mobile because the fixed bg can jitter and snap as it tries to reposition itself as the user scrolls, but it sounds like fixed may not be working, so try background-attachment:fixed; instead of the shorthand. Also try removing "center center fixed". Dai also has a good point about trying a smaller image.

Comment: Here's a somewhat similar question/solution regarding a full-screen fixed background issue on Android you may find helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034651/background-image-goes-to-solid-colour-after-dynamic-content-is-added-on-android

Comment: Body CSS propperties and mobile devices are not always a good idea. Lot's of errors can occur when running a site on a mobile browser, because they tend ignore the propperties within body tag, for example the `overflow` proppertie. May I suggest you make a wrapper element and put it all in there? Also, I recommend you using images with a max size of about 200 kb  preferly even less. (optimize them for the web in Photoshop or any other tool). Else you might wanna rethink your strategy in this case, since maybe data isnt pulling in as quick as your average internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same body declarations under a new media query defining screen size constraints and preferably pull a new image - mypicture-mobile.jpg that has been resized keeping in mind mobile displays. 
Try

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) { /*change 480 to targeted device width */
body {
    background: url(mypicture-mobile.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; /* set to 100% instead of cover to fit screen */
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}
```

A little playing around will reveal your solution, give it a shot

Hope this helps.